# Error in read.table command with the 'sep' argument

Tags: r

I am trying to read following table from the text file. Here is how my text file looks like:

> ```
> 12 333  5
> 1 1234 14
> 20988 432
> 145677 34
> 78 954 34
> 9087 4 51
> ```

my R command is as follows

```
trial1 <- read.table("readtabletrial.txt",sep=c(1,3,5,7),col.names=c("t1","t2","t3","t4"))
```

when I run command I get

> - invalid 'sep' argument

I think that white space I have in my txt file might be an issue. But I cannot erase them since they are part of the structure. So how do I produce table which looks as follows:

```
12  3   33  5
1   12  34  14
20  98  8   432
14  56  77  34
78  9   54  34
90  87  4   51
```

I apologize for low quality example. But I am working with fairly large data-set of similar type. I cannot generate reproducible example from that data and I don't know how to save "txt" file and R data in R so that I can use them in my questions.

Comment: But each line has width of 9 if blank/white space are counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output, it seems that your columns are separated by fixed width, so you can try the `read.fwf`:

```
con = textConnection("12 333  5
+ 1 1234 14
+ 20988 432
+ 145677 34
+ 78 954 34
+ 9087 4 51")

read.fwf(con, widths = c(2,2,2,3))
  V1 V2 V3  V4
1 12  3 33   5
2  1 12 34  14
3 20 98  8 432
4 14 56 77  34
5 78  9 54  34
6 90 87  4  51
```

Comment: Thank you @Psidom.